# Should propensity distributions be normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution

When you use a model to predict the propensity of customers responding to a campaign. Should the distribution of the propensities be normally distributed or skewed to one side?

Comment: How are you measuring "propensity"?

Comment: We are outputing a probability between 0 - 1 from a ridge regression. The target variable was a 1 = responder and 0 = non-responder.

Comment: @AndrewSz, if we're talking 0-1 data, that's binomial distribution territory. As $n$ increases, binomial data are approximately Gaussian (normal).

Comment: @scouser As a general proposition, that is incorrect. Not all processes satisfy the conditions of the CLT.

Comment: @whuber in general, I wouldn't suppose that the CLT applies. However, in the case of binomial data, am I correct? I don't want to post inaccurate answers.

Comment: @Scouser I don't even see how the CLT makes any kind of statement about these data at all.  It's an assertion about limits of standardized sequences of sums (or means), but says nothing whatsoever about the original sequences of values (the "binomial data"). Just because a value is in $[0,1]$ and might be interpreted as a probability does not mean it originates from binomial data or a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

A probability cannot be strictly normal as it has limits and the normal distribution does not.

But I know of no reason why a propensity (as you are using it) should be even approximately normal.